# How do I make hidden description text push the content upwards when it shows

Tags: jquery, css

With this current set up: http://jsfiddle.net/FMqbP/2/

How can I change the effect so that when I hover over the image, the description doesn't fade in but rather comes up from the bottom pushing everything upwards. Similar to the boxes seen [here](http://socialdesignhouse.com/work/)?

**Code:**

```
<article class="project ">
    <section class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQbn0.gif" alt="image" />
        <section class="description">
            <hgroup>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <h3>Cat1, Cat2, Cat3</h3>
            </hgroup>
            <p>Description</p>
                <small class="screenshot"><a class="single-image" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQOva.gif">View Screenshot</a></small>
            <span>Launch <a href="http://test.com" target="_blank">Website</a> | View <a href="test2">Case Study</a></span>
        </section>
    </section>
</article>
```

**CSS:**

```
.project { border:1px solid #efefef;color:#fff;float:left;height:292px;margin:0 20px 20px 0;overflow:hidden;padding:3px;width:292px }
article.right { margin-right:0 }
.project .thumbnail { background:#222;height:292px;position:relative;width:292px }
.project .description { display:none;left:10px;position:absolute;top:10px;width:272px }
.project .description a { color:#fff }
body.home .project .description p { border-bottom:1px solid #777;margin-bottom:10px;padding-bottom:10px }
.project .description span { border-top:1px solid #777;float:left;margin-top:5px;padding-top:5px;width:272px }
.star { line-height:10px }
.screenshot { line-height:10px }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    $('img', this).stop(true,true).fadeTo(200, 0.1);
    $('.description', this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    $('img', this).stop(true,true).fadeTo(200, 1);
    $('.description', this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: You're asking for total rewriting of what you have - can't you try something yourself first?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize that. I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: it's OK JDK, the jsfiddle was a good enough start - btw I just pulled the code into the question to back up the fiddle for future reading, it's generally useful to have both in case fiddles get deleted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need any positioning, just use a negative margin on the image and the `overflow: hidden` that's on the `article.project` will take care of it

in this example I use the jQuery  to find the height of the `description` element then move the image upwards by that same height on mouseover,the decription isn't hidden it's just clipped by the overflow, so whe you move the image upwards by the same height as it the description moves up too and becomes visible

#### Example fiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/pHs4b/)

using your HTML above:

CSS:

```
.project {
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    color:#fff;
    float:left;
    height:292px;
    margin:0 20px 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:3px;
    width:292px;
}

.project .thumbnail {
    background:#222;
    width:292px;
}

.project .description {
    background: #444;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: block;
}

.project .description a { color:#fff }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    var desH = $('.description').outerHeight();
    $('img', this).css({"margin-top" : -desH});
}, function() {
    $('img', this).css({"margin-top" : 0});
});
```

or

#### Added

jQuery to animate the "slide"

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    var desH = $('.description').outerHeight();
    $('img', this).stop().animate({"margin-top": "-" + desH + "px"}, 1000 );
}, function() {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: That's beautiful. However, if done in this method, is it possible to use jQuery to make the description go up smoothly?

Comment: yes you could use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of CSS for the top margin.. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/pHs4b/4/)